# Create buffer around point with Turf

Tags: javascript, leaflet, web-mapping, turf

This code is not working and I don't know why?

```
function getlatlong(b,d){
   return b,d;
}

function buffer(feature){
    var point = {
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: getlatlong(feature.properties.x,feature.properties.y)
  },
    properties: {}
};
    var unit = 'meters';
    var buffered = turf.buffer(point, 10, unit);
    var result = turf.featurecollection([buffered, point]);

    L.geoJson(buffered).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

It might have to do with your getlatlong() function. I would try to troubleshoot by first replacing `coordinates: getlatlong(feature.properties.x, feature.properties.y)` with `[1,1]` or some other simple known X and Y. If that works then your issue is with this. If not you've ruled that out.

I don't see anything misspelled or punctuation missing so after that I can't see what would stop it. An error message would help at this point.

Comment: thank you for your replay,I tried with coordinates (40.5454,1.6544) but always without result ??

Comment: Open the console feature for your browser and trace any errors and add them to your question. If there aren't any then add that fact to your original question and maybe someone with a better eye can see the issue.

Comment: this is the correct  code  to display a buffer around point:

Comment: var pt = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [2.17279,44.04812]
  }
}; 

 var b = turf.buffer(pt,500,"meters");
var bufferLayer500 =L.geoJson(b).addTo(map);
bufferLayer500.setStyle({color: "#FFFF00"});